# Escaping Pipe "|" in for loop with call, getting data after "|". Does not work

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, scripting

I have been trying to read a line with Pipe "|" in it.
I have notice that without escaping pipe ^|, it will just ignore the whole line.
So i added it, but it now seems to just read the line till the pipe "|" only.

Text:

```
Running: Microsoft Windows 7|2008
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows 2008
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows 2008
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows XP|2003
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows 7|2008
```

Code:

```
@echo off
set local

set "file1=C:\Users\Intern3\Downloads\Nmap\1.txt"
echo %date%, %time% > report1.csv

FOR /f "usebackq delims=^|" %%a IN ("%file1%") DO (
echo %%a
pause
CALL :process %%a)

goto :eof

:process
IF "%~1"=="Running:" echo "Operating System:", %~2 %3 %4 %5 %6 >>        
report1.csv
```

I added echo %%a in for loop the check the output.
I use if to check the line for "Running:"
I use ^| but it only reads till "|" only 
What i need is the whole line, not including "Running:"

The Output i will get from the code:

```
04/12/2017 Wed, 11:44:11.42 
"Operating System:", Microsoft Windows 7   
"Operating System:", Microsoft Windows 2008   
"Operating System:", Microsoft Windows 2008   
"Operating System:", Microsoft Windows XP   
"Operating System:", Microsoft Windows 7
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with

```
FOR /f "usebackq delims=^|" %%a IN ("%file1%") DO (
```

which will tokenise the data line based on the provided delimiter set.

The line is interpreted as

*anyofthedelimiters*Token1*anyofthedelimiters*Token2*anyofthedelimiters*Token3*anyofthedelimiters*Token4

for as many tokens as exist on the line.

You can include `tokens=1,2,3` in the options along with the `delims=` clause (i prefore *before* the `delims=`) and this selects the nominated tokens, applying them to the succeeding metavariables, so if `%%a` is nominated as the metavariable, then `tokens=1,2,3` would assign token1 to `%%a`, token2 to `%%b` and token3 to `%%c`. The selected token numbers need not be sequential, so `tokens=1,3` would assign token1 to `%%a`and token3 to `%%b`.

The special token `*` means "all of the rest of the line, verbatim, after tthe highest nominated token number"

So, selecting `tokens=1,*` in that data line would deliver the remainder of the line after the `|` to `%%b`.